# Removing ..'s in boost filesystem::complete

Tags: c++, boost, file-io

This should be simple: I'm composing an absolute path with boost filesystem, however it's returning a really ugly path:

```
D:/Projects/SomeDir/vc10/../resource/plugins/SomeFile.dll
```

Is there a boost way of automatically handling .'s and ..'s?

All I'm doing is:

```
boost::filesystem::complete("../resource/plugins/SomeFile.dll")
```

it's using boost::filesystem2.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
boost::filesystem::complete("../resource/plugins/SomeFile.dll").normalize()
```